# Excel file download not working on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have a strange problem.
we have a website, from where the user can download excel files. In my local system the excel file is downloading ok, but in the life site the excel download it is not working.

I have observed that if I open remotely the server machine, teh excel download suddenly works on the life site too, but if I close the remote it does not work.

I think that it is a permission issue, but I could not realize yet, what can be the problem.

I have tried these settings:

Navigate to Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
Locate the MS application giving you trouble (eg: “Microsoft Excel Application” for Excel or “Microsoft Word 97 – 2003 Document” for Word)
Right click > Properties
On the security tab: Select Customize under Launch and Activation Permissions and click Edit…
Add the account under which the site is running (eg: Network Service) and assign Local Launch & Local Activation permissions

this is what I have founded on the net, but it is not working...
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Content-Disposition` header in your response

```
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = "MyFile.xlsx",
            Inline = false,
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```